# Use custom field in front end of website

Tags: custom-fields, profile

We are testing your application CiviCRM and we tried to create a custom field as contact reference for all kind of contacts.

However though in the preview on the back end this field works fine, when you try to use on the front ebd (chrome, IE, Mozilla) the active search does not work (it doesn't allow to search for the contacts in database).

Example:

Front end (Custom Profile Field “Visita à Loja” - It is a Contact Reference Field - It was suppose that when you select the field, active search was functional. But it’s not!)

[image]

When you see the back-office profile and you select “Preview all fields” of this profile, everything works properly:

- “Data da Prospecção” - It has a Calendar Icon that when you select, a popup calendar appears so you can select date (in front office the icon doesn’t appear)
- “Visita à Loja” - Active search is functional, allowing you to search for contacts in database. However in front office this doesn’t work (as you may see above)

[image]
Can you help
best regards
JSousa

Comment: Please add the version of CiviCRM and the name of the CMS and its version

Comment: CiviCRM 4.7.12.

Joomla Version: Joomla! 3.6.4 Stable

Answer (score 4):

There are instructions on the screen where you create contact reference custom fields:

[image: Contact reference note]

Do your front-end users have the required permissions?

Comment: “thanks for your answer.
But i will explain better my problem. I didn’t make any restrictions to permissions. In fact i accessed in back office with the my account (Super User) and works, after this i accessed in front office with the same access (Super User) and the custom fields don’t work.
I don’t make any restrictions but the access in the front office to these fields has to be through a registred user (User menu).
Can you help me?
best regards